# JsonConvert.SerializeObject object contains string field with \r\n in it

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm doing this in c#:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
   StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml
};
String jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseModel, settings);
context.Response.Write(jsonString);
```

responseModel contains (among other fields) a string field called Msg.

When the Msg field contains a string like 'Hello \r\n how are you?' , it seems that the \r\n breaks the validness of the resulting json string (?!).

In fiddler I got the message:

```
HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure"

[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.
```

Any other value for Msg, without the \r\n the above works fine.
Any thoughts on how to handle this elegantly?

Comment: I just tested `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseModel, settings)` with a `Msg` string including `\r\n`, and the string is properly escaped as specified in the [JSON standard](http://json.org/).  Maybe there's a problem on the server side?

Comment: Can you supply a short example that demonstrates the problem? Please include a JSON string that exhibits the problem.

Comment: @dbc and andrew whitaker .... i found the problem. I was trying to slim down the example as per your requests, and found out I was wrong in my previous thoughts ... it is not malformed json that causes the problem, some lines above the code I showed, I also assigned the Msg string to the HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription field ... and there lies the cause .. if that field is assigned with a string containing \r\n i get this error.... My appologies for not finding this earlier, thanks for the help!